# Find dependencies for particular column across multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, dependencies

I'm looking to find references to a particular column throughout all of my databases. the script below checks to see if the column exists in other tables across databases but I want to go further to check to see where it is used in the queries that input into the tables/views

```
Create table #yourcolumndetails(DBaseName varchar(100), TableSchema varchar(50), TableName varchar(100),ColumnName varchar(100), DataType varchar(100), CharMaxLength varchar(100))



EXEC sp_MSForEachDB @command1='USE [?];
    INSERT INTO #yourcolumndetails SELECT
    Table_Catalog
    ,Table_Schema
    ,Table_Name
    ,Column_Name
    ,Data_Type
    ,Character_Maximum_Length
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME like ''%oracle_vendor_site_id%'''

select * from #yourcolumndetails
Drop table #yourcolumndetails
```

Comment: Pretty sure there is no easy way to do this.

Comment: Do be careful using sp_MSForEachDB. It will sometimes skip databases. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/ For the problem at hand you could get SQL Search from redgate. It can search your entire server for a column name including procedures.